# Can I tag any user while posting a query?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

While posting a question, I can tag only communities related to the query. But I was wondering that is there any way to tag the user who has a good response record in answering the queries in a particular area for e.g. my query is related to JAVA and apart from tagging the community "JAVA" in it, I can tag a particular user?

Comment: It's still called "Java", not "JAVA".

Comment: Or this: [How could I notify Stack Overflow's expert users about my new question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103086/how-could-i-notify-stack-overflows-expert-users-about-my-new-question)

Comment: Or this: [Stackoverflow should send question to experts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133105/stackoverflow-should-send-question-to-experts)

Comment: Or this: [Notification when someone reference you in a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138503/notification-when-someone-reference-you-in-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

No we can't. Because Stack Exchange if run by community not by any particular user. Anyone can give you useful answer to your question.

Comment: "...Stack Exchange is run by community not by any particular user..." Well, there are theories about Jon Skeet and that all users are just bots he wrote to keep him busy...

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't tag or notify particular users in your questions.  The top users in the most popular tags would get buried in these notifications if this were allowed.